# Text size within an PreferenceScreen

Tags: android

I have xml file that defines some preference screens like the following example

```
<PreferenceScreen  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"          
   android:key="root_preferencescreen">

    <PreferenceScreen  android:key="general_sett" android:title="general settings" />
     ....

    <PreferenceScreen  android:key="extras_sett" android:title="extras settings" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

I would like to be able to increase the font size for the text of the preference screen , but because the within a  preference screen  there is no android:textsize tag , i have no idea how to accomplish that !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make a `TextView` layout xml that looks something like this:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:id="@+android:id/title"
/>
```

and set the layout of your preference category in your `preferences.xml` like this:

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Category Title"
    android:layout="@layout/pref_category"
/>
```

As long as the `TextView` has the id `@+android:id/title` you can make the layout look however you want.  There is also a way to do this with styles that I haven't quite figured out.

Comment: Awesome... nailed it! :)

Answer (score 12):

You can simply add `android:textSize` inside your theme for preference screen:

e.g :

```
<style name="settingsTheme" parent="PreferenceThemeOverlay">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_ten</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimaryLight</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/WindowAnimationTransition</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorTextBodyLight</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorTextCaptionLight</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
```

Your `SettingsActivity` class :

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_settings);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.bodylayout, new PrefsFragment())
            .commit();


}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}
}
```

`PrefsFragment` class :

```
public class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle bundle, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Context myContext = this.getActivity();
    //set your theme
        myContext.setTheme(R.theme.settingsTheme);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settingspreference);
    //do other stuffs
        }
    //.....
        }
```