# How to wrap preference title?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences

In this picture, the title of my `Preference` does not wrap around its parent.

How can I make the title wrap to a new line?

Thanks.

[image]

xml:

```
<CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="keypref"
        android:summary="Summary text does wrap around the borders"
        android:title="The title of this preference is" >
</CheckBoxPreference>
```

Comment: If the length of `title` getting very long means and when its getting focus means, it'll run through like in `marquee`style na. Did you see that one?

Comment: @mobile::i think you can overlap with text view

Comment: @mobile:: please check out this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3612019/1021695

Comment: @SpK I don't understand your comment, can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: Would be nice if marquee automatically/magically just work as Praveen said.. but it doesn't..

Answer (score 1):

You would need to make custom layout which resembles default (android internal) CheckBoxPreference. In that xml text view of title should be with ellipsize set to Marque, repeat limit indefinite and scrollable set to horizontal. Than you can set layout of CheckBoxPreference with:

```
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="key_checkbox_pref"
    android:summary="Summary text does wrap around the borders"
    android:title="The title of this preference."
    android:layout="@layout/custom_checkbox_preferences_layout">
```

Hope that would work ;)

Answer (score -1):

Just an update to this. It's a `String` so you can use `\n` to create a newline.

```
<CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="keypref"
        android:summary="Summary text does wrap around the borders"
        android:title="The title of this preference\nis this." >
</CheckBoxPreference>
```

Comment: This wouldn't work very well on different screen resolutions.

Comment: this doesn't work if you use `android:title="@string/some_string"` where you put into a strings.xml `<string name="some_string">the string I want \n to wrap</string>`. Here the `\n` is ignored.

Comment: Correction: a `\n` is always ignored. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616238/how-to-wrap-a-preference-title-really