# How to wrap a preference title? (Really)

Tags: android, android-preferences

Please don't point me to [How to wrap preference title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349784/how-to-wrap-preference-title) as it doesn't work for the case where (as I commented) you use a `@strings/` reference to a **strings.xml** file.

If you use

`android:title="@string/some_string"`

and put

`<string name="some_string">the string I want \n to wrap</string>`

into **strings.xml**, the `\n` is ignored.

Comment: look [here][1] , you should use a line break


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460256/string-resource-new-line-n-not-possible

Comment: @Roman Blachman: thanks, but the line break `\n` it's exactly what is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all `title`s inside preference screen are expected to be **single line**.
 I don't think declaring as `android:title="The title of this preference\nis this."` will work. This will also ignore `\n`.

So, my suggestion is, make title single line and make a summary to describe it.

```
<CheckBoxPreference android:key="extention"
    android:title="@string/title"
    android:summary="@string/summary"
    android:defaultValue="true"
    />
```

Note: `\n` will work for summary

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't work also for a string with no `@string/...` reference. I needed this to always put an `(experimental)` wrapped at the end of the title. It will do its job also at the end of the (already present) summary. Thanks.

Comment: But in the summary I want to show the selected value by %s. Is there in the xml to show in the summary %s concatenated with a string(@string/summary)?

Comment: This may not be the accepted answer. Your solution preclude the real purpose of `android:summary`. There is an actual solution for achieve that?

Answer (score 4):

For most Android versions, there is no exposed API to allow line wrapping on Preference titles. This leads to the unfortunate common bug of truncated/faded text on medium-to-long titles, especially on small screen devices in portrait orientation:

```xml
<PreferenceScreen
    android:key="my_pref_key"
    android:title="A Long Preference Title that should wrap to multiple lines" />
```

[image: Before - Single-line preference titles, in Holo and Material Theme]

But there are 2 ways to workaround it:

**1. The easy way - But this only works on Android 8 (API 26) and above:**

Use [`android:singleLineTitle="false"`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference?#attr_android:singleLineTitle) like this:

```xml
<PreferenceScreen
    android:key="my_pref_key"
    android:title="A Long Preference Title that should wrap to multiple lines"
    android:singleLineTitle="false" />
```

**2. The hard way - Custom Preference Child layouts - This works on all Android versions:**

For Preferences that have long titles, use a **custom layout** on them ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240576/customizing-the-layout-of-a-preferencescreen)), where the **TextView has explicitly turned off single-line text**. But you have to set the layouts programmatically, because the themes are different between Android 4 (Holo theme) and Android 5 and above (Material theme).

**`SettingsFragment.java`** or **`SettingsActivity.java:`**

```java
PreferenceScreen myPreferenceItem = (PreferenceScreen)
    getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("my_pref_key");

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    myPreferenceItem.
        setLayoutResource(R.layout.preference_child_material_customized);
} else {
    myPreferenceItem.
        setLayoutResource(R.layout.preference_child_holo_customized);
}
```

[image: After - Multi-line preference titles, in Holo and Material Theme]

**Example for `res/layout/preference_child_material_customized.xml:`**

Copy this file from your Android SDK/platforms/android-22/data/res/layout/
**preference_child_material.xml** ([like this one](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/core/res/res/layout/preference_child_material.xml)) and customize it:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+android:id/icon_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minWidth="40dip"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+android:id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dip" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingTop="16dip"
        android:paddingBottom="16dip">

        <TextView android:id="@+android:id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

        <TextView android:id="@+android:id/summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
            android:layout_alignStart="@android:id/title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSecondary"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"
            android:maxLines="10" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Preference should place its actual preference widget here. -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+android:id/widget_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minWidth="58dip"
        android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Notice the line **`android:singleLine="false"`** on the TextView.

For `res/layout/preference_child_holo_customized.xml`, you should copy it from your Android SDK/platforms/android-19/data/res/layout/
**preference_child.xml** or **preference_child_holo.xml** ([like this one](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/core/res/res/layout/preference_child_holo.xml)) and customize it in a similar way.

Comment: It requires API 26 - not API 27.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work with `CheckBoxPreference`.

Comment: @Dmitry I corrected it to API 26, thanks. I don't know how to fix it for CheckBoxPreference.

Comment: @galaxigirl I believe it does work with `ListPreference`. On Android 8 and above, you should use  `android:singleLineTitle="false"`. On Android 7 and below, you must use a custom layout, like `android:layout="@layout/preference_child_material_without_icon"` -- This is a similar layout to `preference_child_material_customized.xml`, but you should remove the LinearLayout block that contains the icon.

Comment: @Mr-IDE I tested it on API 28 - regular Preference is wrapped, ListPreference is ellipsized

Comment: @galaxigirl I don't understand why it doesn't work for you. I have attached an image here to show what I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TO9tJ.png  -- Maybe it can help. I tested it on `android.preference.Preference` and `androidx.preference.Preference`.

Comment: @Mr-IDE I believe it works for you because of the customized layout. Does it work for you on API 26+ without it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `app:singleLineTitle="false"` with `androidx.preference:preference`, e.g.:

```
<SwitchPreferenceCompat
        app:defaultValue="false"
        app:iconSpaceReserved="false"
        app:key="important_switch"
        app:singleLineTitle="false"
        app:title="@string/pref_switch_title" />
```

Comment: For me, `singleLineTitle` took effect when I used `SwitchPreference`, but not when I used `SwitchPreferenceCompat`.